# DatagridView cell change color

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I want to change datagridview cell color but ı have a condition with that.
if a data exist in the database cell color change to green if not it has to be red.

```
SELECT TrCode FROM SmsTableInvoice AS sms WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM SmsTableStFiche AS stfiche WHERE sms.TrCode=stfiche.TrCode)
```

this is my code ı try use in visual stuido with c#
is there anyone to help with this

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kUwpRmESh18n2bMYzDcAXkl_EygXn4Af/view?usp=sharing

Hi i solved that problem

this is my code

```
    `
    public void Control()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dtsatis.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
            if ((dtsatis.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value) != null)
            {
                cellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
                cellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;

            }

            else
            {
                cellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                cellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
            }

            dtsatis.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle = cellStyle;
        }
    }
```

and you have write form load method .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional formatting of DataGridView cell data - Change color on negative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42246878/conditional-formatting-of-datagridview-cell-data-change-color-on-negative)

Comment: no . it's not to answer . I try to make in desktop app.

Comment: Can you show a picture of the grid and specify what cells should be colored green or red. Also, any code that attempts to color the cells. The current code does not appear to have anything to do with “coloring” a grids cell.

Comment: @JohnG ı added to picture as a lişnk can yo check it?